# Gmail push new mail notifications to Linux?

Tags: linux, gmail, push

Is there any way to coax Gmail into pushing new-mail notifications into my Linux machine, without using a full-on graphical mail client like Thunderbird?

**edit**: Thanks for all the responses, but (unless I'm mistaken) these applications all *poll*, none of them receive notifications *pushed* from GMail.

Also, I'd prefer a console-based program, as this will be running on a headless server.

Comment: AFAIK Gmail doesn't push notifications at all, which means all notifiers must poll... but I may be unaware of some enterprise edition feature or other.

Comment: Instant notifications is possible using Gmail's free service (Thundebird is capable). I believe the enabling feature is IMAP IDLE.

Comment: Yuval: yea, alfplayer is right. Gmail does push notifications, both to IMAP and when you're in the web interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a program called checkgmail

(http://checkgmail.sourceforge.net/)

that will sit in your gnome taskbar. I know there is a plasma widget for KDE

(http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php/gmail-plasmoid?content=101229)

that does something similar, although from what I've read, it might be a little broken.

The program Docky2 has a pretty good gmail notifier built in if you use a compositing window manager like compiz or metacity.

(https://launchpad.net/docky)

I don't know of any terminal based checkers if you don't have an X11 at all.

Comment: The command line equivalent is 'biff'

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu or another debian-based distro, `checkgmail` should be in your repository.

Comment: Do all of this clients support push (instant) notifications? I've only found Thunderbird to have this capability.

Comment: As alfpayer said, all of these (including, as far as I can tell, checkgmail) are polling not push based.

Comment: Ah, good point. Sorry, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

[Mail Notification](http://www.nongnu.org/mailnotify/) supports Gmail. It can check multiple accounts simultaneously so you can also use it to notify you of new mail in Evolution, Thunderbird or IMAP and POP accounts.

Comment: Ah, thanks – this one does support push notifications… But, alas (and this is my fault, I'm sorry) I didn't make it clear that I wanted an X11-free app.

Answer (score 1):

Is this any good?

http://gmail-notify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That does look nice, but unfortunately it uses polling, not server-push, too.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old but it came up in my search and I thought I'd update. Evolution now supports IMAP+ or IMAPx which enables IMAP IDLE, and so gmail can push mail to it.

http://chenthill.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/evolution-with-improved-imap-support-imapx/

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't push. You can receive an atom feed:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#GmailAtomFeed

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu, try GmailWatcher;

ppa:loneowais/ppa

Comment: What is `ppa:loneowais/ppa`?

Comment: On Ubuntu you can add this to your list of software sources and you'll get automatic updates for all the apps present in this repository.